# range of continous linear operator between banach spaces with closed algebraic complement

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, direct-sum

Let X, Y be Banach spaces, and let A ∈ L(X, Y ).
Suppose that there exists a closed subspace W ⊂ Y so that Y is the algebraic direct
sum of ran A = A(X) and W. (That is, every y ∈ Y can be written as y = Ax + w
for unique Ax ∈ ran A and w ∈ W.)
I need to show that ran A is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The natural linear isomorphism between Banach spaces
$$(X/\ker A)\times W\to Y,\quad (x\bmod{\ker A},y)\mapsto A(x)+y$$
is continuous [hence bicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)), and sends the closed subspace $(X/\ker A)\times\{0\}$ onto $\operatorname{ran}(A).$